# How to pass an array through fetch to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, parameter-passing, use-state

I'm trying to pass-through an array from a fetch call in App.js to my other component. I can console.log the array fine in the other component but as soon as I try to loop through it I get the Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps";

const Map = ({ Locations }) => {
  const [selectedLocation, setselectedLocation] = useState(null);

  const [GoeLocation, setGoeLocation] = useState(null);

  console.log(Locations.Imgdata);

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={8}
      defaultCenter={{
        lat: 41.8989,
        lng: -87.6123
      }}
    >
      {/* {Locations.Imgdata.map((LocationCod, i) => (
                        <Marker
                            key={i}
                            position={{
                                lat: LocationCod.latitude,
                                lng: LocationCod.longitude
                            }}
                            onClick={() => {
                                setselectedLocation(LocationCod);
                            }}
                        />
                    ))} */}

      {selectedLocation && (
        <InfoWindow
          position={{
            lat: selectedLocation.venue.location.lat,
            lng: selectedLocation.venue.location.lng
          }}
          onCloseClick={() => {
            setselectedLocation(null);
          }}
        >
          <div>
            <h3>{selectedLocation.venue.name}</h3>
            <p>{selectedLocation.venue.location.address}</p>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
};

export default withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));
```

Comment: Are you passing Location as prop to Map?

Comment: yes, I am trying to pass it as a prop so can loop through it in MAP.js

Comment: kindly share sample Locations data

Comment: Location data looks like this 0:
farm: 66
id: "49831425552"
isfamily: 0
isfriend: 0
ispublic: 1
owner: "19417430@N00"
secret: "0340ffbbb5"
server: "65535"
title: "Former Citizens State Bank Re-Muddle, Lincoln & Melrose, Chicago"
__proto__: Object
1:
farm: 66
id: "49762964997"
isfamily: 0
isfriend: 0
ispublic: 1
owner: "83194813@N00"
secret: "a929455094"
server: "65535"
title: "Let's Play Two"
__prot

Comment: Can you also share App.js ?

Comment: useEffect(() => {async function example() {let response1 = await fetch(`url1`);
    let json = await response1.json();
    const promises = json.photos.photo.map((i) =>
     fetch(`url2`);
    const response2 = await Promise.all(promises);
    const json2 = await Promise.all(response2.map((res)=>res.json()));
    return {
     dataset1: json,
     dataset2: json2
    };
   }
   example().then((i) => {setLocations(i.dataset1.photos.photo);
     setImgdata(i.dataset2);
    }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
    });
  },
  [
   query
  ]
 );

Comment: <Map googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA8i9z0T-J6oIs6Rrb7FUqz0rM1jipwrEg&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`}
    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    Locations={{ Imgdata }}
   />

Comment: The problem is not in Map.js, it is in App.js. I  can not pinpoint exactly where your problem, but my gues is in how you fetch and construct Locations.If your App.js does not contain sensitive data, do share more of its code - remember not to share your credentials